# How to fix the issue with virtual directory mapping in weblogic 12c

Tags: weblogic12c

I am using virtual-directory-mapping in weblogic.xml. However, when i am trying to access pdf files from local system i am always getting 404
URL: http://machinename:port/PrintPreviewSBL/temp/119033.pdf
The pdf file exist the location /opt/oracle/product/DEV/BI/custom/temp. I want know what is the change required in mapping

**Weblogic.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE weblogic-web-app PUBLIC "-//BEA Systems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 8.1//EN" "http://www.bea.com/servers/wls810/dtd/we
blogic810-web-jar.dtd">

<weblogic-web-app>

<container-descriptor>
<index-directory-enabled>true</index-directory-enabled>
</container-descriptor>

<virtual-directory-mapping>
     <local-path>/opt/oracle/product/DEV/BI/custom/temp</local-path>
     <url-pattern>/temp/*</url-pattern>
  </virtual-directory-mapping>

<context-root>/PrintPreviewSBL</context-root>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to remove the subir "temp" from the local-path:

```
<virtual-directory-mapping>
    <local-path>/opt/oracle/product/DEV/BI/custom</local-path>
    <url-pattern>/temp/*</url-pattern>
</virtual-directory-mapping>
```

Does this work?